# Would I get judged on this site?

Tags: discussion

If I were to make a wrong answer, would people lean towards downvoting my answers more in the future?

Comment: Unlikely, but not impossible. Write good answers and good things happen.

Comment: *Would I get judged on this site?* The purpose of upvotes and downvotes is to judge the quality of questions and answers, not the people writing them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People down-vote bad answers, so that could impair your ability to post on the site at all, as there's a more-or-less secret internal formula the system uses to decide if a poster is so bad (or badly behaved) that they should be banned for some period.  Note that deleting your (bad) posts typically makes that more likely, not less, as deletions are discouraged in this scoring.  The theory is that people who write mostly good posts don't need to delete the odd bad post, and we don't want bad answers and the people who write them misleading people.  If this was not done we'd be plagued by the flat-earth brigade and other people determined to push non-mainstream theories (the site is purely for mainstream physics).

If your answers were so bad they drew the attention of people who frequent the site, who tend to be more active in reviewing and voting, then your future posts might come under more intense scrutiny.  Any flaws in those future posts would thus be more likely to generate more down-votes.

One other point: the system does automatic checking for serial (or even group serial) voting targeting someone.  You're therefore unlikely to have all your posts targeted by a small group of people in a brief period.  The details of the algorithm checking this are secret, but I've been a target of such voting and the system automatically detected and corrected it, so I know it's there.